# amazon EC2 load balanced - how to deploy web app?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

We're looking to move to amazon cloud using EC2 and RDS.

I'm looking at load balancing, which I would like to do, two servers, each in a different availability zone to protect against downtime.

My question is how to deploy web applications and updates to them? I assume there is a better way than individually updating the files on each EC2 server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In systems past, I have used the [vcs](https://github.com/bruce/puppet-vcsrepo/) puppet module to ensure that the appropriate source code is installed on my system, in addition to using puppet to build the configuration files for the apache/nginx server that I'm using.  Another possibility is to push your application in a deployable state (if you're not using a scripting language) to Amazon S3, and have your run-time scripts pull the latest build from your S3 bucket.